# A closed form of mean-field equations

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains, expectation

Assume that a system at time t, for example number of costumers in a line at time $t$ which is denoted by $q(t)$, follows a Markov chain with these dynamics (probabilities)

$$P(q(t+\Delta t)-q(t)=1)=\alpha \Delta t$$
$$P(q(t+\Delta t)-q(t)=-1)=\beta\hspace{0.1cm}v(q(t)) \Delta t$$

for some known constant rates $\alpha$ and $\beta$. where $v(x)$ is piecewise function

\begin{equation}
\label{v}
v(q)=\begin{cases} 
      0 & q \leq 0 \\
      \frac{q}{q_{*}} & 0\leq q\leq q_{*}\\
      1 &q\geq q_{*}
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Where $q_*$ is a constant.
 Using Dyknin formula we can find that the density, $E[q(t)]$=the expected number of customers at time $t$, can be obtained from this differential equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt} E[q(t)]=\alpha-\beta E[v(q(t))]
\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}

I was wondering if there is any way to find a closed form above differential equation  which means to find an expression for $E[v(q(t))]$ in terms of $E[q(t)]$.

Some efforts: In above equation replace $E[v(q(t))] = v(E[q(t)])$. Clearly this is not a good assumption because $v(x)$ is a concave function so according to Jensen's inequality we have 
$$E[v(q(t))] \geq v(E[q(t)])$$

So replacing $E[v(q(t))]$ by $v(E[q(t)])$ may not give us a good estimation of exact solution of above ODE. I've done simulations for $E(q(t))$= the exact solution of differential equation (non-closed one), and the solution of closed form differential equation where $E[v(q(t))]$ is replaced by $v(E[q(t)])$ and this solution is not close to the exact solution. 
There are some other suggestions like using a quadratic equation in form of
$$E[v(q(t))]= a\hspace{0.1cm}E[q(t)]^2+b\hspace{0.1cm}E[q(t)]+ c$$
and then trying to find coefficients $a$, $b$ and $c$, but this effort also fails in some cases!
I think any effort should use the nature of function $v(x)$ but till this moment I don't know how to find it. So please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: What is $v(x)$?

Comment: It seems this post was self-vandalized (it originally had a real contents). OP, please just delete your post if you want, instead of self-vandalize.

Comment: I restored the content;  @Daaan , if you wish to remove this question, the way to go is to delete the entire post (there is a button for that) --- please don't delete only the content.